Moongose findOneAndDelete() not working with certain parameters
I am making contact CRUD application with Node.js, Express and MongoDB. In my delete function, with the help of Postman I am able to delete contacts by ID, but if I try to delete by name or number I get an error saying:
path: '_id',
"BSONError: input must be a 24 character hex string, 12 byte Uint8Array, or an integer at new ObjectId"

which tells me that it's still searching for the ID even if I wanna find and delete by name and or number.
I tried taking the id field out of my code and I was able to search by name but if my code, not my postman url has all 3 it doesn't work.
const deleteContact = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {
            id: contactId,
            Name: contactName,
            Number: contactNumber
        } = req.params;
        let queryObject = {};
        if (!contactId && !contactName && !contactNumber) {
            return res
                .status(400)
                .json({ msg: 'Please provide either an ID, Name, or Number' });
        }

        if (contactName) queryObject.Name = contactName;
        //if (contactId) queryObject._id = contactId;
        if (contactNumber) queryObject.Number = contactNumber;

        // Perform the database operation
        let contactDelete = await Contact.findOneAndDelete(queryObject);

        res.status(200).json({
            contactDelete,
            message: `Contact deleted successfully!`
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error', error);
        res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Server Error!' });
    }
};

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Name: {
        type: String,
        //required: [true, 'Must provide name'],
        //trim: true,
        //maxLength: [10, 'name cannot be more than 10 characters']
    },
    Email: {
        type: String
        //required: [true, 'Must provide name']
    },
    Number: {
        type: Number
        //required: [true, 'Must provide name'],
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Contacts', contactSchema);

I just realized that no matter what I put as a number or name, it deletes a random one.

I'd print out queryObject before the call to findOneAndDelete and make sure the correct data is being sent from the client.

Can you share your Contact schema?

Also, you need to log queryObject and share it here. If it's an empty object, then it deletes the first found data without matching

Can you share your route to see what req.params is expected to be parsed like?

Guess into the blue/hint, you are doing a AND operation on your validity check: if (!contactId && !contactName && !contactNumber) {, but say "Please provide either an ID, Name, or Number", Switch to OR (||) operation/check.

is the destruction of req.params valid? I've never seen it before like that. Did you validate it that those correctly being destructed? I'd use const {x,y,z} = req.params  and log them.

Is the issue still persisting ?

The filter document queryObject  is empty in the statement below. And when it is empty, it deletes the first document returned in the collection.
let contactDelete = await Contact.findOneAndDelete(queryObject);

The corner issue is the validation below failing by a logical error. It includes contactId which does not take part in the filter. It means when there is only contactId, then the validation will pass, and will not send 400 status code. However the filter document will be empty in this case which leads to the undesired random deletion.
if (!contactId && !contactName && !contactNumber) {

Please remove contactId from the above statement, then it will start throwing status 400 in the right way. This will guide to the actual issue and solution.

Hi, Please see if this post helps you.
